# Authentication settings in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I was following MVC music store tutorials and went all good. All the models are using MusicStoreEntities data context, however I did not found how AccountModel is setup, Should I use MusicStoreEntities class for account model as well ? Is there any exaple ? pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a MVC MusicStore targeting MVC 4. What I see on official website is a MVC 3 example [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/)

R u using above link?

Microsoft do provide an MVC 4 tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4), r u referring this link? A good starting point for MVC 4.

Alright first of all MVC 4 usage SimpleMembershipProvider (SMP) which does not support WSAT.

To see an example create a new project and choose MVC 4 internet application template, you will see AccountController which is setup to make use of default providers. The AccountModel has classes required by SMP (You can add more columns as per your need). The providers are configured using web.config file and you can extend it by implementing you own.

Since WSAT is not available you would want to create users and role using WebSecurity API which is simple enough to use.

For a comparison of SMP with previous providers I found this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx) most helpful and complete.

For a summary of SMP I find this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/Aligned/archive/2012/08/30/mvc-4-authentication.aspx) helpful as its concise and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use the **Web Site Administration Tool** this is the built-in ASP.NET Configuration website.

Jon Galloway in fact has screenshots on the music store right here.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7

Good luck!

Comment: Can we not use the account controller that is built automatically when we create the project ?

Comment: Sure, but If you download the latest version of it and you do not see it modified to your liking, I would go with that link I sent to you or if you don't like how they are doing that Then if it was me, and I did not need a custom LDAP provider situation I would use "Simple Provider" there are many references to it along with the MVC 4 books demonstrate it.

Comment: @TomStickel - I was under impression WSAT not supported for MVC 4? Is that not true?

Comment: Correct,  WSAT is not for MVC 4 , so depending on your goals, you can look at both.   However this project might help you   https://github.com/kahanu/Security-Guard